# bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: bash, gnome, security, malware, hacking

Just received this error >>

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

then the disk partition went into READ-Only mode ; also noticed gnome-software was communicating
both upload and download over the internet.

Here is a description of this 2012 Security Issue (below) **  ;
so I expect, but don't know how to confirm True/False, that 2020 Security patches
MAY have "Fixed This" by Bombing Out and Setting Disk Read-ONLY as I just Witnessed.
2012 Security Issue Description ** Here >> https://www.halfdog.net/Security/2012/TtyPushbackPrivilegeEscalation/ and Here >> https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17311808

Steps Taken so far:
(Simply) Reinstalled existing software as per :
gnome-software (version 3.20.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.13) will be re-installed
gnome-software-common (version 3.20.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.13) will be re-installed

Any suggestions to confirm the hack failed, or to prevent the hack from setting partition
to Read-Only from happening again appreciated.

Comment: Resolved / Closed Per friend Michael - “ These vulnerabilities are not relevant to a storage failure. Check dmesg at the time of failure (and before rebooting!) to see what is really going on.  “  

.. Yes this makes sense now, it was (likely) a disk error from this log rotation via logrotate, details here  >>  

  Nov  7 16:46:17 mc-M-8C09 trackem[2486]: [uid:0 sid:1148 tty:(none) cwd:/var/lib/logrotate filename:/bin/systemctl]: systemctl kill -s HUP rsyslog.service  

  And next time I will .. Check dmesg at the time of failure (and before rebooting!) to see what is really going on.